# How to Call an Application with Parameters in NPAPI for Mac

Tags: npapi

I try to create a simple NPAPI which passes an URL to Safari.

plugin_invoke method is below:

```
    bool plugin_invoke(NPObject *obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) {
        // Make sure the method called is "open".
        NPUTF8 *name = npnfuncs->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
        if(strcmp(name, plugin_method_name_open) == 0) {
            npnfuncs->memfree(name);
            BOOLEAN_TO_NPVARIANT(false, *result);
            // Meke sure the arugment has at least one String parameter.
            if(argCount > 0 && NPVARIANT_IS_STRING(args[0])) {
                // Build CFURL object from the arugment.
                NPString str = NPVARIANT_TO_STRING(args[0]);
                CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithBytes(NULL, (const UInt8 *)str.UTF8Characters, str.UTF8Length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, NULL);
                if(url) {
                    // Open URL with the default application by Launch Service.
                    //OSStatus res = LSOpenCFURLRef(url, NULL);
                    //CFRelease(url);


                    OSStatus resultt = eventNotHandledErr;

                    //FSRef appRef;

                    FSRef appRef = {0};
                    Boolean isDir =true;

                    resultt = FSPathMakeRef((UInt8 *) "/Applications/Safari.app", &appRef,
                                            &isDir);

                    LSApplicationParameters appParams = {0, kLSLaunchDefaults};

                    appParams.application = &appRef;
                    appParams.version = 0;
                    appParams.flags = kLSLaunchDefaults;

                    resultt = LSOpenApplication(&appParams, NULL);

                    BOOLEAN_TO_NPVARIANT(resultt == noErr, *result);



                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        npnfuncs->memfree(name);
        return false;
    }
```

Currently it just invokes Safari but URL can not be passed.

How can I pass an example URL to the Safari in NPAPI? I read LSOpenFromURLSpec might work but I could not create the code.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation for Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), especially LSOpenURLsWithRole.

FYI, nothing about your question is NPAPI-specific, it's just about launching a Mac application from another process. In general you'll get more answers if you don't post general questions as NPAPI questions, since *way* more people know the answers to general Mac questions than to NPAPI-specific questions.